# Image showing downloaded but not getting opened from browser when clicked

Tags: javascript

Image showing downloaded after i click on download image its showing Failed-No file in browser.I have done something wrong in providing download path may be. Here is my code:

```
       <button id="download-button" class="btn--success">Download</button>
<script>
    document.getElementById('download-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', '/Downloads');
        link.setAttribute('download', 'https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg');
        link.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

this final `a` tag should look like this:

```
  <a href="https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg" download>
       <img src="https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg">
  </a>
```

but you set link

```
link.setAttribute('href', '/Downloads');
link.setAttribute('download', 'https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a downloadable link to achieve dynamically downloading functionality. For more reference refer <kbd>[createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)</kbd>

**UPDATE**

1. First, you need to convert the requested Image to base64 format
2. To achieve this, we need to download the requested image.
3. To download image, Implement  Fetch and Promise together
4. After, Image get downloaded, convert it into blob `res.blob()`
5. FInally your code for dynamically creating link with little code change.
6. The entire code snippet is below

   ```
   async function getBase64ImageFromUrl(imageUrl) {
       var res = await fetch(imageUrl);
       var blob = await res.blob();

       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         var reader  = new FileReader();
         reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
                 resolve(reader.result);
             }, false);

         reader.onerror = () => {
            return reject(this);
         };
         reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      })
   }


   getBase64ImageFromUrl('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'+'https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg')
   .then(function(result) {

       var link = document.createElement('a')
       link.href = result
       link.style.display = 'none';
       link.setAttribute('download','');
       document.body.appendChild(link);
       link.click();
       document.body.removeChild(link)}
   )
   .catch(err => console.error(err));
   ```

**Note** - to avoid CORS issue, I have attached the `'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'` URL at the beginning of the image URL.

Comment: Its downloaded but unable to access it in photo viewer. When i open downloads from my browser.I get this link in recent downloads blob:http://localhost:8023/8349a020-8af6-47cb-93a4-b4c2b6f9fe41

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
document.getElementById('download-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg');
    link.style.display = 'none';
    link.setAttribute('download', '');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

The resulting `a` tag will be like this

```html
<a href='https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg' download style="display:none;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

html download attribute will work, only those case when image and html file both are  in same server . it means as per your image path your html file must be in https://tinyjpg.com/ server

you can update your script by this

```
    document.getElementById('download-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', 'https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg');
        link.setAttribute('download',"download");
        link.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    });
```